# Unable to import Pandas in AWS Lambda layer

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pip

I uploaded python pandas to Lambda and when I run the Lambda, I see the following error:

```
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': C extension: No module named 'pandas._libs.interval' not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first."
```

I am really not sure what is supposed to be going on here. But for more context, I created a directory called "python" and then I run the following line on my terminal

```
python3.8 -m pip install pandas -t .
```

I then zip the "python" directory and then create a new layer and upload the zip file.

Struggling to see where I am following short.

Comment: A [web search](https://www.google.com/search?q=pandas+%22lambda+layer%22) revealed several articles on this topic.

Answer (score 8):

Have you considered using publicly available layer for `pandas`, for example from this popular repository:[keithrozario/Klayers](https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers)?

For instance, the list of layers available for python 3.8 is [here](https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers/blob/master/deployments/python3.8/arns/us-east-1.csv) for `us-east-1`.

In this case, for `us-east-1` you could add the `pandas` layer using:

```
arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:770693421928:layer:Klayers-python38-pandas:16
```

#### Update, making custom layer

I just created the custom layer with `pandas` and `xlrd` and can confirm that it works.

The technique used includes **docker tool** described in the recent **AWS blog**:

- [How do I create a Lambda layer using a simulated Lambda environment with Docker?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/)

Thus for this question, I **verified it**  as follows:

1. Create empty folder, e.g. `mylayer`.
2. Go to the folder and create `requirements.txt` file with the content of

```
pandas
xlrd
```

3. Run the following docker command:

```
docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task "lambci/lambda:build-python3.8" /bin/sh -c "pip install -r requirements.txt -t python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/; exit"
```

4. Create layer as zip:

```
zip -r mypandaslayer.zip python > /dev/null
```

5. Create lambda layer based on `mypandaslayer.zip` in the AWS Console. Don't forget to specify `Compatible runtimes` to `python3.8`.
6. Test the layer in lambda using the following lambda function:

```
import json

import pandas
import xlrd

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    print(dir(pandas))
    print(dir(xlrd))
```

The function executes correctly:

```
['BooleanDtype', 'Categorical', 'CategoricalDtype', 'CategoricalIndex', 'DataFrame', 'DateOffset', 'DatetimeIndex', 'DatetimeTZDtype', 'ExcelFile', 'ExcelWriter', 'Float64Index', 'Grouper', 'HDFStore', 'Index', 'IndexSlice', 'Int16Dtype', 'Int32Dtype', 'Int64Dtype', 'Int64Index', 'Int8Dtype', 'Interval', 'IntervalDtype', 'IntervalIndex', 'MultiIndex', 'NA', 'NaT', 'NamedAgg', 'Period', 'PeriodDtype', 'PeriodIndex', 'RangeIndex', 'Series', 'SparseDtype', 'StringDtype', 'Timedelta', 'TimedeltaIndex', 'Timestamp', 'UInt16Dtype', 'UInt32Dtype', 'UInt64Dtype', 'UInt64Index', 'UInt8Dtype', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__docformat__', '__file__', '__getattr__', '__git_version__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', '_config', '_hashtable', '_is_numpy_dev', '_lib', '_libs', '_np_version_under1p16', '_np_version_under1p17', '_np_version_under1p18', '_testing', '_tslib', '_typing', '_version', 'api', 'array', 'arrays', 'bdate_range', 'compat', 'concat', 'core', 'crosstab', 'cut', 'date_range', 'describe_option', 'errors', 'eval', 'factorize', 'get_dummies', 'get_option', 'infer_freq', 'interval_range', 'io', 'isna', 'isnull', 'json_normalize', 'lreshape', 'melt', 'merge', 'merge_asof', 'merge_ordered', 'notna', 'notnull', 'offsets', 'option_context', 'options', 'pandas', 'period_range', 'pivot', 'pivot_table', 'plotting', 'qcut', 'read_clipboard', 'read_csv', 'read_excel', 'read_feather', 'read_fwf', 'read_gbq', 'read_hdf', 'read_html', 'read_json', 'read_orc', 'read_parquet', 'read_pickle', 'read_sas', 'read_spss', 'read_sql', 'read_sql_query', 'read_sql_table', 'read_stata', 'read_table', 'reset_option', 'set_eng_float_format', 'set_option', 'show_versions', 'test', 'testing', 'timedelta_range', 'to_datetime', 'to_numeric', 'to_pickle', 'to_timedelta', 'tseries', 'unique', 'util', 'value_counts', 'wide_to_long']
['Book', 'FMLA_TYPE_ARRAY', 'FMLA_TYPE_CELL', 'FMLA_TYPE_COND_FMT', 'FMLA_TYPE_DATA_VAL', 'FMLA_TYPE_NAME', 'FMLA_TYPE_SHARED', 'MMAP_AVAILABLE', 'Operand', 'Ref3D', 'USE_MMAP', 'X12Book', 'XLDateError', 'XLRDError', 'XL_CELL_BLANK', 'XL_CELL_BOOLEAN', 'XL_CELL_DATE', 'XL_CELL_EMPTY', 'XL_CELL_ERROR', 'XL_CELL_NUMBER', 'XL_CELL_TEXT', '__VERSION__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', 'biff_text_from_num', 'biffh', 'book', 'cellname', 'cellnameabs', 'colname', 'compdoc', 'count_records', 'decompile_formula', 'dump', 'dump_formula', 'empty_cell', 'error_text_from_code', 'evaluate_name_formula', 'formatting', 'formula', 'info', 'mmap', 'oBOOL', 'oERR', 'oNUM', 'oREF', 'oREL', 'oSTRG', 'oUNK', 'okind_dict', 'open_workbook', 'os', 'pprint', 'rangename3d', 'rangename3drel', 'sheet', 'sys', 'timemachine', 'xldate', 'xldate_as_datetime', 'xldate_as_tuple', 'xlsx', 'zipfile']
```

Comment: I am using exactly this and it is causing the following error:

"Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'. Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd.",

Comment: @MatthewMetros Ok. I will update the answer with how to make such custom layer. In the meantime, can you provide some small lambda snippet code for testing and what also do you require in the layer?

Comment: @MatthewMetros Answer updated how to make working layer specially for your use-case.

Comment: I am not familiar at all with Docker. Where do you recommend I go to get up to speed with this program?

Comment: def get_zip_df(FileName):
    # df = pd.read_excel('/tmp/filename.xlsx')
    os.chdir('/tmp/')
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    print(os.listdir())
    wb = load_workbook(FileName)
    ws = wb['Report 1']
    data = ws.values
    columns = next(data)[0:]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
    return df

Comment: @MatthewMetros Generally you just need to have Docker installed. Nothing else should be required to create the layer.

Comment: @MatthewMetros I can't run your code, as I don't have your excel file. Maybe you can come out with an example that does not require custom excel files?

Comment: For anyone who's getting an "invalid reference format" error when running the Docker command on Windows:

 - Change "$PWD" for ${pwd} (without the inverted commas too)
 - Make sure to run it within a folder whose path doesn't contain any whitespace

(and to create the layer zipped file, substitute /dev/null for os.devnull)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Klayers is what worked for me. I tried creating my own layer by downloading pandas wheel, unziping, and zipping it, and upload it as custom layer, and it does not work. The Klayers (numpy and pandas) is work for me in the end.

Answer (score 4):

If you are working with pandas on AWS, it is better to use the AWS SDK for pandas (AWS Datawrangler) instead of installing pandas or importing a third party layer.

You can learn more about installing by clicking on the following link:

https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html

Just add layer from the AWS layers:
[image]

Or via its ARN:

```
arn:aws:lambda:<region>:336392948345:layer:AWSSDKPandas-Python<python-version>:<layer-version>.
```

For example:

```
arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:336392948345:layer:AWSSDKPandas-Python37:1.
```

The full list of ARNs is available [here](https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/layers.html).

Comment: What is the size of this layer?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of installing the pandas through pip, you could try with the wheel files as well. This worked for me. Just download the required wheel files, and unpack the files into the directory which you are planning to upload as a layer, zip the directory, and upload it to the lambda layers.

[Refer to this for step by step guide...](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-add-python-pandas-layer-to-aws-lambda-bab5ea7ced4f)