# AWS: Adding extra Layers: no module found

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have trying to import a layer, but i get the same error: No module, whatever i do.

These are the steps i do:
First i create a venv in ubunt:

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

i activate the venv

```
source ./venv/bin/activate
```

i install pandas:
pip3 install pandas

Then i zip in the venv:

```
zip -r my.zip ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas
```

Is this folder correct?
I tried also with zipping the whole site-packages, which did not work neither.

I upload it as layer and i add the URN to my function and i put

```
import pandas
```

in the lambda function.
The output, when i run the function is:

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pandas'",
```

Comment: Have you checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63421063/unable-to-import-pandas-in-aws-lambda-layer/63421091#63421091)? It shows how one can make correctly pandas layer, or use existing one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after watching a youtube video where is mentioned, that the .zip file should have the path: python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/

The link to the video is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cz8QjmgfGHc